# Multi UserControls GUI WPF Window with Buttons and ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

With help of the program "Balsamiq Mockups 3" I draw example GUI which I want to achived: [Link](http://s11.postimg.org/fgf8twcoj/New_Mockup_1.png)

Outside rectangle: On left side there are Buttons from 1 to 6, which show all the same content (same UserControl) only the instance is different and then is there Button 7 with have totally different UserControl windows (so two different UserControls)

Inside rectangle: Inside of "Button 1 to 6" is ComboBox, which with a change of Selected Item of ComboBox also change Content of inner rectangle.

I already make something simillar to this [link](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/) only thats I make two different ItemsControls with same ItemTemplate. Its working, but it is little bit to complicated. Specially because I need to take date from every choosen option (save ComboBox selected item, select setups inside UserControls,...)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish and what is your current code?

Comment: Why do you need different itemsControls? I assume you have a viewmodel list for userControl1 models for button 1 to 6 & other viewmodel list just for userControl2. You need to have one base class for both the viewModels for which you will be defining a list & then a single ItemsControl with ItemTemplate for that list.